# Adding descriptive words to field names and getters when the meaning might be clear from the class context

Tags: java

I have a class for templating HTML selectors called `Selectors`.
In it I have named the fields `name` and `age` and the corresponding getters `getName()` and `getAge()`. 
Now it may seem a little confusing on its own but when given the class context I sort of believe that it's clear that you are getting the selector value and not the value of what's beign selected (i.e the person's name). For example:

```
Selectors webPageSelectors = new Selectors()
nameSelector = webPageSelectors.getName()
```

Is this clean and clear or should I add kind of repetetive words to field names and getters like `nameSelector` and `getNameSelector()`? Or perhaps something like this: `webPageSelectors.getForName()?` where the field is named `forName` (as if 'selector for name')? Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid this question is really opinion-based. Personally I think that small is beautiful, and the context is clear enough, no need to add an extra info.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is clear if you know what it is intended to do.
However if you are worried, you can always use JAVA-DOC to provide clear documentation as to what each function does. This helps a lot in development teams.
Plus. is `nameSelector` of type `Selector` ? if so, then yes renaming the attributes in the `Selectors` class to include the type is much easier to understand. If you decide to do the latter, just make sure you don't do it to primitive type attributes.

This is just an opinion, you are free to code however you like.

Comment: The ```nameSelector``` would be of type ```String``` actually. That's actually 
something I hadn't considered. Thanks for pointing that out!